# Plotting Catalan surface

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot a Catalan surface with the following code, but nothing happens,  it runs but does not display my image. is there anyone who knows what I need to change in the code? Thank you!

```
catalan[a_][u_,v_]:={a(u-Sin[u]Cosh[v]), a{1-Cos[u]Cosh[v]},-4a Sin[u/2]Sinh[v/2]}
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[Append[catalan[1][u,v], FaceForm[Blue,Green]]], {u,0,4*Pi},{v,-2,2}, PlotPoints->{45,20}];
```

Comment: See [The four kinds of bracketing in the Wolfram Language](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/BuildingUpCalculations.html#8720)

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `{,}` as brackets  in the definition  of `catalan`:

Try ( I changed  `Append part` to `PlotStyle->...`)

```
catalan[a_][u_, v_] := {a (u - Sin[u] Cosh[v]), 
  a (1 - Cos[u] Cosh[v]), -4 a Sin[u/2] Sinh[v/2]}
ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[ catalan[1][u, v]], {u, 0, 
   4*Pi}, {v, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> {45, 20}, PlotStyle -> FaceForm[Blue, Green]]
```

[image]

Hope that's what you're looking for!

Comment: It's still not working, but thanks for the intention.

Comment: @user981656 Without `Apppend` it works fine!

Comment: hello, yes, this is exactly the surface I'm trying to plot, I don't know why it still doesn't work for me, is it possible to plot the image without  the Box (Boxed->False) once again if it's not too much trouble? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @user981656  Did you try to evaluate my code in a fresh kernel?

Comment: @user981656 ...and add the plot options `Boxed->False,Axes->False` to plot without box

Comment: yes, I did. it doesn't stop running the code, it never happened before, so I don't know what's wrong

Comment: I removed the `;` and checked my code on a fresh kernel (Mathematica v12.2): works fine!

Comment: Yes, it finally works! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome!